# Linux Hosting files outside the htdocs directory

Tags: linux, directory, xampp, lamp, lampp

I followed [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xampp#Hosting_files_outside_the_htdocs_directory) instructions to be able to host files outside of the htdocs directory, but I alwyas get 'Access Forbidden' (https://gyazo.com/af49cb00720fa4bd80e969320bd51042).

The file those permissions: `$ ls -l ~/Documents/code/xampp/
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 julian users 3337 Apr 10  2017 test.php`

How do i fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aache is not able to execute the php file, because apache don't have permission to execute the test.php file.

Try giving permission to the file.

**sudo chmod +x test.php**

Any user can execute the file.So change the file group to www-data and give executable permission.

**sudo chown root:www-data test.php**

**sudo chmod 775 test.php**